# How Can I Create An Empty Mat And Draw Lines On It?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, mat

My current code

-declares the Mat just by name

```
Mat Scribble;
```

-draws two lines directed at it

```
line(Scribble(leftRect),cvPoint(LEFx,LEFy),cvPoint(leftey.xPos,leftey.yPos), cvScalar(0,250,0),3,8,0);

line(Scribble(rightRect),cvPoint(RIGa,RIGb),cvPoint(rightey.aPos,rightey.bPos), cvScalar(0,250,0),3,8,0);
```

-shows the Mat

```
imshow(windowName,cameraFeed);
```

That last one is what breaks the program, and I have a feeling it's because the Mat's dimensions haven't been declared. But whenever I try to use
    Mat::create
it breaks anyway. Is there any other way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to initialize the size of `Mat Scribble`. Here is a code for drawing a line. You can change its start point and end point for your intention.

```
Mat Scribble = Mat::zeros(250, 250, CV_8UC3);        // 250 x 250 Mat
line(Scribble, Point(10, 10), Point(100, 100), Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1, 8);
namedWindow("Scribble", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Scribble", Scribble);
waitKey();
```